# Reading multiple raster tif as dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, raster, tiff, geopandas

I want to read several raster tif files and get a dataframe as output. Each raster has two bands.

I want to get something like this as output:
[image]

I tried something to read all tif files but I don't know how stack them as dataframe :

```
import numpy as np
import glob 
import rasterio as rio

final = []
tif_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(Repo_img, r'*.tif')) 

for f in tif_files:
    im = rio.open(f).read(1)
    imarray = np.array(im)
    final.append(imarray)

final = np.asarray(final)
```

Anyone can help please ?

Comment: Does `pd.DataFrame(np.stack(final))` work?

Comment: thanks for your back ! That's not works...I get ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 2, 22223, 28679)

Comment: I see. I think If you ravel each array before adding it to the list that should do the trick

Comment: Otherwise I’d recommend rioxarray and xarray for working directly with geotiffs. You could concatenate them all together and dump the resulting dataset into a dataframe with `ds.to_dataframe()` if you want to continue in pandas.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Okay I tried and I get a result but not the expected one... I have an array with the pixel dimensions of my image while I would like only one column for each band with the value of each pixel for that band in row 

I'll check rioxarray and xarray :)

Comment: This is not at all how I conceptualize handling raster data. Once you've accomplished this, what's next?

Comment: @PaulH When I retrieve this dataframe, I do similarity tests between the columns to get matrices of temporal changes for each pixel. Anyway, this is what I would do with it.

Comment: Ahh, in that case, I would expect a performance boost if you kept the data as an `N x M x T` numpy array and performed your calculations along the last axis

Comment: @PaulH Nice ! Indeed the code which I have is time consumer... Have you an exemple of script for that ?

Comment: @CarlBethuel do you have an example of the calcs your running? `numpy.dstack(list_of_arrays).mean(axis=2)` could be demonstrative, but your overall goals are pretty vague

Comment: @PaulH I want to do a similarity test (the Kullback-Leibler test seems to be suitable for my study). To explain a bit more: 
I have a time series of rasters and I'm looking to quantify the change between these rasters. That's why I import all my images under a dataframe to be able to compare the columns between them and simplify the thing (in my opinion). If you have solutions that are less demanding on the processing side, I'm interested.

Comment: I need to see more code than what you have provided here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing your last line with the following should do the trick

```py
final = pd.DataFrame(
    # concatenate column vectors
    np.hstack([
        # first flatten, then convert row vectors to columns
        f.ravel().reshape(-1, 1)
        # for each array in your list
        for f in final
    ])
)
```

See the [numpy beginner's guide to reshaping arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#can-you-reshape-an-array) for more info.